# Keyword 'const' does not make the value immutable. What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

There's the [const definition](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#_const) in *Exploring ES6* by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer:

> `const` works like let, but the variable you declare must be
>   immediately initialized, **with a value that can’t be changed
>   afterwards**. […]
>
> ```
> const bar = 123;
> bar = 456;  // TypeError: `bar` is read-only
> ```

and then he writes

> **[Pitfall: const does not make the value immutable](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#_pitfall-const-does-not-make-the-value-immutable)**
>
> `const` only means that a variable always has the same value,
>   but it does not mean that the value itself is or becomes immutable.

I am little confused with this pitfall. Can any one clearly define the `const` with this pitfall?

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) explanation is clear: *"The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is an **object**, this means the object itself **can still be altered**."* (emphasis mine)

Comment: It means that if the value is mutable, (e.g. if it is an object) then you can still mutate that object (e.g. update, add, remove properties).

Comment: The variable itself is immutable (the reference it holds to a space in memory is fixed) but the value (that space in memory) is not necessarly immutable, specially when the value is an object where you can access it's space using more than just one variable (pass by reference)!

Comment: `const x = "immutable"` is immutable, because `String` is immutable. `const` prohibits merely reassignment.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir pass-by-reference does not apply here. JS does not support pass-by-reference btw.

Comment: @zeroflagL _JS does not support pass-by-reference_ ??? o.O

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: passing *a* reference (what JavaScript does for objects) is not the same as pass *by* reference (which describes the relationship between bindings, the value is irrelevant).

Comment: @FelixKling That's what I said (for objects).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: no, you said pass *by* reference, which JavaScript doesn't support. It only passes objects *as* references. That's different. It's probably what you meant, but used the wrong terminology. It's a common misconception.

Comment: @FelixKling I still not get it, is the problem in english or in JS itself? Is **_objects are passed by reference in JS_** not the same as **_JS passes objects as reference_**?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Yes, that's the issue. The term *pass-by-reference* [has a very specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir This [subject](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-8-evaluation-strategy/) is more complex than you think

Comment: @FelixKling emmm.. So pass by reference is passing the variables them selves as references (In C++: `void foo(int &bar)` if you're familiar with C++)! I get it now!

Comment: Once again we see that banning pointers from a language to make it simpler doesn't *actually* ban pointers from the language (e.g., Java's NullPointerException) and just makes some "simple" concepts confusing (for some) and some harder concepts impossible to understand (for some) (e.g., memory leaks in a GC language due to unintentionally holding an object "too long" combined with GC promotion to the oldest generation).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir With Javascript, you don't pass an alias of the reference, but its copy (as a value). Thus, you share the passed object type and reassignment doesn't interfere.

Comment: @ftor I'm not discussing wether JS allow passing aliases or not (I know it doesn't) all I'm trying to say is that the terminology **passed-by-reference** is used when passing aliases or not (now I know it is), and since JS doen't allow that then **passed-by-reference in js has no meaning**!

Comment: @ftor In my very first comment, what I meant by **_objects are passed by reference_** is that their value is passed as a reference not the value of the variable that holds that reference. But turned out that the terminology **passed by reference** is exclusively used on variables them selves not on their values and thus it can't be used in JS as it's not supported (that I know)!

Comment: @Mukund: Where did you get that "definition" from? Please cite (link) your source(s)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) sums it up nicely:

> The `const` declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.

More succinctly: `const` creates an immutable binding.

In other words: `const`, like `var`, gives you a mutable chunk of memory in which you're storing something. However, const dictates that you must keep referring to that same chunk of memory – you can't reassign the variable to a different chunk of memory, because the variable reference is constant.

To really make something constant and unchanging after you've declared it, you need to use something like `Object.freeze()`. However, that's shallow and only works on key/value pairs. Freezing an entire object takes a bit more effort. To do so repeatedly in a performant way is yet more challenging. If you really have a need for that, I'd recommend checking out something like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: In C terms: If a normal `var x` is a `struct Object *x`, a `const x` is a `struct Object *const x`. The pointer can't be changed; the thing it's pointing to can.

Answer (score 154):

When you make something `const` in JavaScript, you can't reassign the variable itself to reference something else.  However, the variable can still reference a mutable object.

```
const x = {a: 123};

// This is not allowed.  This would reassign `x` itself to refer to a
// different object.
x = {b: 456};

// This, however, is allowed.  This would mutate the object `x` refers to,
// but `x` itself hasn't been reassigned to refer to something else.
x.a = 456;
```

In the case of primitives such as strings and numbers, `const` is simpler to understand, since you don't mutate the values but instead assign a new value to the variable.

Comment: This answer is much better than the accepted one. More succinct and contains actual example code. (In other words, *gets to the point*.) +1

Answer (score 15):

### Rebinding

`const` and `let` declarations control whether rebindings (aka reassignments) between identifiers and values are allowed:

```js
const x = "initial value";
let y = "initial value";

// rebinding/reassignment

try { x = "reassignment" } catch(e) { console.log(x) } // fails

y = "reassignment"; // succeeds
console.log(y);
```

### Immutability

Immutability is controlled at the type level. `Object` is a mutable type, whereas `String` is an immutable type:

```js
const o = {mutable: true};
const x = "immutable";

// mutations

o.foo = true; // succeeds
x[0] = "I"; // fails

console.log(o); // {mutable: true, foo: true}
console.log(x); // immutable
```

Answer (score 1):

## const means: you can't change the initially assigned value.

First, define, what is a **value** in js. Value can be: Booleans, strings, numbers, objects, functions, and undefined values.

*Like: People are calling you with your name, it's not changing. However, you change your clothes.* The **binding** between the people and you is your name. The rest can change. Sorry for the weird example.

So, let me give you some examples:

```js
// boolean
const isItOn = true;
isItOn = false;           // error

// number
const counter = 0;
counter++;                // error

// string
const name = 'edison';
name = 'tesla';           // error

// objects
const fullname = {
  name: 'albert',
  lastname: 'einstein'
};

fullname = {              // error
  name: 'werner',
  lastname: 'heisenberg'
};
```

```js
// NOW LOOK AT THIS:
//
// works because, you didn't change the "value" of fullname
// you changed the value inside of it!
fullname.name = 'hermann';

const increase = aNumber => ++aNumber;
increase = aNumber => aNumber + 1;      // error

// NOW LOOK AT THIS:
//
// no error because now you're not changing the value
// which is the decrease function itself. function is a
// value too.
let anotherNumber = 3;
const decrease = () => --anotherNumber;

anotherNumber = 10;             // no error
decrease();                     // outputs 9

const chaos = undefined;
chaos = 'let there be light'    // error

const weird = NaN;
weird = 0                       // error
```

As you can see, unless you're not changing the **"first"** assigned value to a const, no error. Whenever you try to change the first assigned value to something else, it gets angry, and it gives an error.

So, this is the second thing you might know when using `const`. Which is, **it should be initialized to a value on its declaration or it will be angry.**

```js
const orphan;                    // error
const rich = 0;                  // no error
```

Answer (score 0):

### `ES6`/`ES2015` `const` keyword:

The `const` keyword is used to declare a block scoped variable (like declaring with `let`). The difference between declaring a variable with `const` and `let` is the following:

1. A variable declared  `const` cannot be **reassigned**.
2. A variable declared with `const` has to be **assigned** when **declared**. This is a logical consequence of the previous point because a variable declared with `const` cannot be reassigned, that's why **we have to assign it exactly once when we declare the variable**.

### Example:

```js
// we declare variable myVariable
let myVariable;

// first assignment
myVariable = 'First assingment';
// additional assignment
myVariable = 'Second assignment';

// we have to declare AND initialize the variable at the same time
const myConstant = 3.14;

// This will throw an error
myConstant = 12;
```

In the above example we can  observe the following:

1. The variable `myVariable` declared with `let` can first be declared and then be assigned.
2. The variable `myConstant` declared with `const` has to be declared and assigned at the same time.
3. When we try to reassign the variable `myConstant` we get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

### Caveat: The variable assigned with `const` is still mutable:

A variable declared with `const` just can't be reassigned, **it is still mutable**. Being mutable means that the data structure (object, array, map, etc) which was assigned to the `const` variable still can be altered (i.e. mutated). Examples of mutation are:

1. Adding/deleting/altering a property of an object
2. Changing the value of an array at a specific array index

If really want an object to be not mutable you will have to use something like `Object.freeze()`. This is a method which freezes an object. A frozen object can no longer be changed and no new properties can be added.

### Example:

```js
const obj = {prop1: 1};

obj.prop1 = 2;
obj.prop2 = 2;

console.log(obj);

// We freeze the object here
Object.freeze(obj);

obj.prop1 = 5;
delete obj.prop2;

// The object was frozen and thus not mutated
console.log(obj);
```