# ES6 module immutability

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, es6-modules

I thought ES6 module exports were always immutable, so I'm pretty confused about the behaviour I'm getting. I have a simple array of colors that I would like to use in multiple components of my Vue application. It is in it's own file like so:

```
export const colors = [
  '#ffb3ba',
  '#ffdfba',
  '#ffffba',
  '#bae1ff',
]
```

Then I import it into the component where I want to use it like this:

```
import { colors } from '../assets/colors';
```

I have a function for picking a random color and then removing it from the list so it isn't picked again for the same component. It's something like this.

```
descriptions.forEach(item => {
      const colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      item['color'] = colors[colorIndex];
      colors.splice(colorIndex, 1);
    });
```

The idea here is to pick a random color from the list, assign it a description and then remove it from the list so a different one is picked on the next iteration of the `forEach`.

The problem is that it seems to be removing the colors from the list permanently. So when I import and try to use the array in another component, there are no colors in it. How can I make it so there is a fresh instance of the `colors` array for every component?

Comment: Make a clone so that you have your list, and then an availableList which updates on a selected or de-selected color. You're importing an array, you can modify the values inside, but you can't re-assign it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 module imports are not immutable, as you have correctly observed.

---

You could create a shallow copy of the array and operate on that one:

```
const copiedColors = [...colors];

descriptions.forEach(item => {
  const colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  item['color'] = copiedColors[colorIndex];
  copiedColors.splice(colorIndex, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The imported *bindings* are not assignable, that's all. They are similar to `const` - you cannot change the variable, [but you can mutate the object it holds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42833540/1048572). To prevent that, freeze the object when exporting it:

```
export const colors = Object.freeze([
  '#ffb3ba',
  '#ffdfba',
  '#ffffba',
  '#bae1ff',
]);
```

> How can I make it so there is a fresh instance of the `colors` array for every component?

Have a look at [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/1048572) for that: just `colors.slice()`. Also you'll want to check out [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/1048572) for how to efficiently get the random colors for your descriptions - there are even [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054543/1048572) that do not mutate the input.

```
import { colors } from '../assets/colors';
import { shuffle } from '…';
const randomColors = shuffle(colors.slice());
console.assert(descriptions.length <= randomColors.length);
for (const [i, description] of descriptions.entries())
  description.color = randomColors[i];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand your solution. When I use `Object.freeze` I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements`.

And what is wrong with my randomization method? The ones you linked are much more complicated.

Comment: Yes, freezing is just a safe-guard to prevent the removes from working. You will still need to make the actual copy using `.slice()` (or `Array.from` or whatever).

Comment: Your randomisation method is really inefficient, repeatedly removing things from the middle of the array has `O(n²)` complexity. Just use the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle (it's not *that* complicated)…

Comment: Does it really matter when there is only 5 items though? I can't make heads or tails of the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

`var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;`

I've never seen variables assigned like this. What does the comma separation mean?

Comment: @MattGween It's just [declaring multiple variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). You might find the code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/1048572) more readable…

Comment: Okay. That's better. I'll try to implement it. Thanks for the help.