# When should packages be saved as const?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm assuming that it depends on the package and whether or not its internal data is changed. I just wanted to make sure because I have seen some package documentation use const and others use var/let and I haven't been able to find any answers to this using google. Right now I'm using let. Would there be any performance improvement from using const on packages that support it?

Comment: You can and probably should always use `const`. No, it does not depend on the package - it's your local variable. [The package object is still mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42833540/1048572)

Comment: By *saved* you mean *imported*? As Bergi notes it, it's not the package which is `const`, it's your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual rule is to always use `const` by default, and only use `let` when necessary, so for imported package it's almost never.